# Divide $(x+1)^2$ by $x-1$ without using longdivision.

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

Dividing a polynomial of degree $n$ with a polynomial of degree $n-1$ gives a polynomial of degree $1$. So,

$$\frac{(x+1)^2}{x-1}=ax+b\Leftrightarrow x^2+2x+1=ax^2+(b-a)x-b$$

Gives $a=1, \quad a-b=2, \quad -b=1$. So $a=1$ and $b=-1.$ The result I get is that $$\frac{(x+1)^2}{x-1}=x-1.$$ Which is far from the correct answer. I can't spot my mistake. I feel that the more I sit and study, the worse at math I become.

Comment: I think it should be $(b-a)=2$...Instead of $(a-b)=2$

Comment: well a must be equal to 1 because factor of $x^2$a and equall to -3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$(x+1)^2$ is not divisible by $(x-1)$ and hence you can't say that the result is a polynomial of degree one. You also can see this fact by seeing that how you proceed you can't solve $a=1 ~~b-a=2$ and $b=1$, therefore doesn't exist a polynomial of degree one which satisfy your result (hence its not divisible by $(x-1)$)

Answer (score 3):

In this case, you are missing out a term, that is remainder. $$(x+1)^2 = Q(x) (x-1) + R(x)$$

Comment: Exactly...because he has in his equation only one parameter its b a is already fixed...so impossible to match the 2 constraints on b

Answer (score 2):

Write $(x+1)^2 = (x-1)(ax+b)+c$ and plug in $x=1$, you get $4=0+c$ so $c=4$. Now

$$ (x+1)^2-4 = x^2+2x-3 = (x-1)(x+3)$$ so $a= 1$ and $b=3$.

Answer (score 2):

As per this equation in your effort: $$x^2\color{red}{+2}x+1=ax^2\color{red}{+(b-a)}x-b$$

Hence, it should be $\,b-a=2$ which is not compatible with $a=1 \, , \,b=-1$.

So, $(x-1)$ is not a divisor/factor of $(x+1)^2$. Rather, you can try adding a remainder, say $\mathrm{c}$, and then solving as follows:
$$\frac{(x+1)^2-c}{x-1}=ax+b$$

Answer (score 2):

$x-1$ doesn't divide $(x+1)^2$ exactly, so there must also be a remainder term of lower degree than $x-1$, i.e.
$$ \frac{(x+1)^2}{x-1} = ax+b + \frac{c}{x-1}. $$
Then you find
$$ x^2+2x+1 = ax^2+(b-a)x+(c-b), $$
giving three equations in three unknowns (you expect a unique solution anyway, so you should have the same number of equations as unknowns).

Comment: It's also worth pointing out that long division is essentially just a systematic way of solving these equations.

Answer (score 1):

$$(x+1)^2=x^2+2x+1=x^2-x+3x -3+4=(x-1)(\underbrace{x+3}_\text{quotient})+\underset{\strut{\rlap{\text{remainder}}\qquad}}{4}$$